# How to use different base class constructors on some condition?

Tags: c#, inheritance

Say, we have two classes:

```
public class A
{
    protected static readonly int DefaultValue = 123;

    int value;

    public A()
    {
        value = DefaultValue;
    }

    public A(int _value)
    {
        value = _value;
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public B(XElement x)
        : base(x.Element("int") == null 
                  ? A.DefaultValue 
                  : (int)x.Element("int"))
    {
    }
}
```

I understand that I could make a parameterless constructor for class B::

```
public B():base()
{
}
```

and have smth like this:

```
B objB = (x.Element("int") == null)?new B():new B((int)x.Element("int"));
```

but I'd love to have this logic encapsulated in class B.

Also I see I can do some kind of static factory method and have it encapsulated (and even make those class B constructors `private` if necessary):

```
public static B GetInstance(XElement x)
{
    return (x.Element("int") == null)?new B():new B((int)x.Element("int"));
}
```

But I'd love to be able to have smth like the following pseudo code:

```
public class A
{
    //don't need this anymore 
    //protected static readonly int DefaultValue = 123;

    int value;

    public A()
    {
        value = 123;
    }

    public A(int _value)
    {
        value = _value;
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public B(XElement x)
        : x.Element("int") == null
              ? base()
              : base((int)x.Element("int"))
    {
    }
}
```

Or is there any other approach which could do the same thing as nice and even better?

Comment: Have you tried playing around with a null int (int?) in the Class A constructor? With a optional parameter you might be able get away with one constructor.

Comment: @Spevy Actually in my real application it's not `int`, but a refernce type. And `null` is not the default value for the base class field. That's why this will not work. Sorry, for misleading by the example in my question.

Comment: @Spevy In the end I did found a completely another way, having used an optional bool parameter in the base class constructor. To my mind, my original approach was whorse than what I have now. As far as your comment made me think that way, could you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried playing around with a null int (int?) in the Class A constructor? With a optional parameter you might be able get away with one constructor.

Answer (score 3):

The *only* condition that can change the base constructor used is the actual constructor that is called - find another approach to the problem :)

A factory method is one way, as noted. Also, I believe [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/) (and possibly other DI frameworks) allows choosing different constructors dynamically based upon argument *values*. Sadly, I do not have enough DI experience ..

Another possibility in this case is to take in `int?` which, while it does change the interface, would allow `null` to be easily coalesced to the default value.

Comment: +1 for *only condition that can change the base constructor* and *find another approach to the problem*. I did found another approach.